# Generic View Returning A Closure Option

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI and i am not sure what the right term for this is. Hoping someone can guide me

Take this generic view for example (this one is incorrect since if i pass a view as parameter, how can it use the fetched data).

```
struct FetchUrlContentView<Content>: View where Content: View {
  var url: String?
  @State var loading = true
  @State var content: (_ data: String?) -> Content
    @State var data: String?
    
    init(_ url: String?, _ loading: Bool, @ViewBuilder _ content: @escaping (_ data: String?) -> Content) {
        self.url = url
        self.loading = loading
        self.content = content
    }
   
  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      if !NetworkTool.hasInternet() {
        NoInternetView()
      }
      else if loading {
        LoadingProgressView()
      }
      else if error {
        SomethingWrongView()
      }
      else {
        content(data)
      }
    }
    .task {
      if let urlLink = self.url {
        fetchContentFromUrl(url: urlLink, { data in
          // This works but from the reused component, how would you call from the closure to set loading to false instead of this.
          // any ideas?
          if let json = data {
              self.data = json
          }
          self.loading = false
        })
      }
      else {
        self.loading = false
        self.error = true
      }
    }
}
```

What i am looking for is something of a way to keep on reusing FetchUrlContentView such that after data is fetched, i could call it like this

FetchUrlContentView(url: "https://www.test.com/", loading: true) { data in
MyView(data)
}

where MyView contains something like Text(data.description)

The code has been editted and i got it to work. partly. My remaining issue is how to call loading = false and set it inside the closure since i want to process data first and parse them before passing it to MyView.

So the sequence would be something like

let array = parse(data)
loading = false
MyView(array)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Create generics with Two Params View and Data.

I would suggest other Generics like:

```
struct AsyncResultView<Success, Content: View>: View {
    let result: AsyncResult<Success>
    let content: (_ item: Success) -> Content

    init(result: AsyncResult<Success>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (_ item: Success) -> Content) {
        self.result = result
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        switch result {
            case .empty:
                EmptyView()
            case .inProgress:
                ProgressView()
            case let .success(value):
                content(value)
            case let .failure(error):
                Text(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

enum AsyncResult<Success> {
    case empty
    case inProgress
    case success(Success)
    case failure(Error)
}
```

Reference:
[AsyncView – Asynchronous loading operations in SwiftUI](https://www.ralfebert.com/ios-app-development/swiftui/asyncview/)

Comment: Hi Toseef. Ill improve my code with that for sure. Thank you for the guide. I edited my code because I got it to work. But one thing is lacking, i do not want loading = false to be called inside FetchUrlContentView but from within the closure. Is that possible? What is the correct word for that solution?

Comment: @chitgoks: Require full working demo to test. [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)